# Need to convert a ssh output to json format

Tags: linux, shell, ssh, json, powershell

I have a piece of code which generates a output as chunk.

```
TIBCO ActiveMatrix BusinessWorks version 6.4.2, hotfix 7, build V103, 2018-07-18 Connecting to the BW Agent using TIBCO ActiveSpaces (Java). Enterprise Edition. Version 2.1.6.011 Connected to BW Agent
Domain: 3APIServices

Name                                               Version  AppSpace                       Profile                        Status          Deployment Status (Running/Total)
AS_CRM_032-CustomerAccount_CRM.application         1.0      AS_CRM_032_AppSpace            PROFILE.substvar               Running         Deployed          (1/1)
a
/home/REBUSCLOUD/kramk/ServiceLive.sh: line 6: /opt1/tibco/tea/2.3/bin/bwadmin: No such file or directory
TIBCO ActiveMatrix BusinessWorks version 6.4.2, hotfix 7, build V103, 2018-07-18
Connecting to the BW Agent using
 TIBCO ActiveSpaces (Java). Enterprise Edition. Version 2.1.6.011
 Connected to BW Agent


Domain: 3APIServices

Name                                               Version  AppSpace                       Profile                        Status          Deployment Status (Running/Total)
AS_DW_021_3APIFailureEvents_DW.application         1.0      AS_DW_021_AppSpace             PROFILE.substvar               Running         Deployed          (1/1)
a
/home/REBUSCLOUD/kramk/ServiceLive.sh: line 6: /opt1/tibco/tea/2.3/bin/bwadmin: No such file or directory
TIBCO ActiveMatrix BusinessWorks version 6.4.2, hotfix 7, build V103, 2018-07-18
Connecting to the BW Agent using
 TIBCO ActiveSpaces (Java). Enterprise Edition. Version 2.1.6.011
 Connected to BW Agent
```

I need the output to be converted to json format like below

```
{
            "Domain": "3APIservices",
            "Name": "AS_CRM_032-CustomerAccount_CRM.application",
             "Version": "1.0",
            "Appspace": "AS_CRM_032_AppSpace",
         },
```

Can some one help me on this?

Below is the piece of code I used. As this is in loop i will get outputs one by one. The thing is I need that to be in json, so that I can use it somewhere else.

```
for f in ls -d /opt1/tibco/bw/6.4/domains/*/appspaces/*; do
 DomainName="${f%%'/appspaces/'*}"
 DomainName="${DomainName##*/}"
 AppSpaceName="${f##*'/'}"
 Command_To_Execute="/opt1/tibco/bw/6.4/bin/bwadmin --propFile /opt1/tibco/bw/6.4/bin/bwadmin.tra show -domain ${DomainName} -appspace ${AppSpaceName} applications"
 /opt1/tibco/tea/2.3/bin/bwadmin show -domain domains -appspace appspaces applications
 if [ "$DomainName" != 'ls' -a "$DomainName" != "-d" ]
 then
eval "${Command_To_Execute}"
  echo "a"
 else
  ""
 fi
done
```

Comment: What is the relevance of the [tag:powershell] tag here?  It would also be helpful if you could show the directory and filenames that the two `*` matches in the `/opt1/tibco/bw/6.4/domains/*/appspaces/*` pattern, as these seem to hold some of the data that you want as output.

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to format output first, and cut away all infos you don't need. Think about fixed fields, keywords and so on...

After that, you may use **jq** to convert to JSON. I used it a couple of times to encode/decode JSON.

https://stedolan.github.io/jq/